Array of string inputs in Vue 3?
I'm trying to present a form using Vue 3 that will contain a list of text input fields.  The fields map to a string[] with a fixed length.  I'd like to be able to set each field's v-model to the corresponding string in the array.  My code thus far looks like this (for the view itself):
<template
    v-for="(myValue, index) in myValues"
    :key="myValue"
>
    <input
        type="text"
        class="form-control form-control-solid mb-3"
        :placeholder="'Choice #' + (index + 1)"
        v-model="myValues[index]"
    />
</template>

The myValues property is declared as a ref<string[]> in my component's setup method. This form renders perfectly.  However, I find that when I go to enter text into one of my <input /> fields, it only allows me to enter a single character before moving focus off the field.  I have to click in the box again, and can then enter another single character.  If I remove the v-model declaration, I can enter as much text as I want in the field.
What is causing this?  I feel like it has something to do with the fact that I'm updating a value in an array, but I'm not sure what to do about it.  Is there a way to handle this use case where I can enter more than one character at a time, but with a v-model?

Could you maybe use v-model.lazy="myValues[index]"? I think that since it's an array and you update a value there, it kind of sends the updated value eagerly to each input and hence, takes away the focus from your input.

As a general rule: you are not supposed to pass myValue as a :key to the loop. Sometimes you can (if hardcoded array for example), but I am sharing the rule and not the exception here.
More details can be found on the documentation.

It is recommended to provide a key attribute with v-for whenever possible, unless the iterated DOM content is simple (i.e. contains no components or stateful DOM elements), or you are intentionally relying on the default behavior for performance gains.

And this is a great article about why using an index is usually a bad idea as a :key.
Here is an official example regarding the usage of the element of an array itself as a :key during an iteration. A similar example in a previous iteration was using a similar approach thanks to nanoid, to generate UUIDs.
In Vue3, the impact of not providing a :key is not that big overall thanks to the optimizations done by the Core team. It was more the case with Vue2. Meanwhile, as a general good practice prefer using something unique for your :key attribute.

Something like this should work well
<input
  v-for="(myValue, index) in myValues"
  :key="myValue.id"
  type="text"
  class="mb-3"
  :placeholder="'Choice #' + (index + 1)"
  v-model="myValues[index]"
/>

Alternatively, you could use v-model.lazy too but it's still a bad practice to pass an index to the :key.
Credits to this answer.

So, myValue is just an array of strings.  There's no "id" property to speak of.

@Shadowman you could then use any kind of package to generate a UUID (like nanoid), this is the only thing that Vue asks for.

The linked answer definitely explains why I'm having the problem, though.  Thanks!  Could I pass "index" as a :key?  Or would that be problematic, too?

@Shadowman you can, check my answer with an explanation

@Shadowman you should not. Prefer not passing anything rather than passing an index that could change and defeat the whole purpose of :key's benefits.

@Shadowman here is a complete answer to that topic: https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/tips-and-gotchas-for-using-key-with-v-for-in-vue-js-3/ (or anything another resource foundable on the Internet, tells you that it's not a good idea to use an index as a key) If you have a hard-coded array, you could I guess!

Prefer using index for :key, otherwise your inputs are re-rendered every time you change the value (that's why you lose the focus). Your values are bound to to indices in the array, so it's valid to use the index as a key in this particular case.

In this particular case, OP should not even use a key: "It is recommended to provide a key attribute with v-for whenever possible, unless the iterated DOM content is simple (i.e. contains no components or stateful DOM elements), or you are intentionally relying on the default behavior for performance gains." Still a better practice to recommend using :key properly all the time than wrongly often and fine others. Especially to a Java developer that does not write VueJS daily.
